# How to stop the updating of YouTube video metrics timing out when updating MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, youtube-api

I am trying to update the details of over 5,000 videos I have in a mysql table but it keeps on timing out after a while.

I basically loop through the records which contain a YouTube video code and look up the details using the YouTube feed API.

Can anyone help explain why and how I can fix it please?

Here's my code:-

```
    <?php

$con = mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "pw");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('We could not connect you to our network at this moment. We apologise for the inconvenience please try again later');
  } 

mysql_select_db("sociallandscaper", $con);

set_time_limit(0);

$ccresult = mysql_query("SELECT vidcode FROM ytt");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ccresult)) {
$c = $c +1;

$vidcode = $row['vidcode'];
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={$vidcode}&v=2&alt=json";
$json_single_vid = file_get_contents($url);
$json_single_vid_data = json_decode($json_single_vid);
$likes = $json_single_vid_data->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'yt$rating'}->{'numLikes'};
$dislikes = $json_single_vid_data->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'yt$rating'}->{'numDislikes'};
$raters = $json_single_vid_data->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'gd$rating'}->{'numRaters'};
$fav = $json_single_vid_data->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'yt$statistics'}->{'favoriteCount'};
$average = $json_single_vid_data->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'gd$rating'}->{'average'};
$comments = $json_single_vid_data->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'gd$comments'}->{'gd$feedLink'}->{'countHint'};

$mSQL = "UPDATE ytt SET vidraters = '$raters',vidrating = '$average',vidlikes = '$likes',viddislikes = '$dislikes',vidcomments = '$comments',vidfavs = '$fav' WHERE vidcode = '$vidcode'";

mysql_query($mSQL);

echo $c."<br/>";
    }

  ?>
```

I would be really grateful for any advice.

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: connect to mysql after the request

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the code and process in smaller chunks. This has the advantage of being able to scale vs something which might only address your problem right now. Also I might add that I don't know what is "timing out" the connection to mysql? The whole script? The connection to youtube?